# Wordpress using hostPath volumes fails to start pods

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

I am using hostPath in PersiistentVolumes for wordpress.
Following [this][1]blog, I did all deployment. But I see pods are failing

```
wordpress-758cfb447d-2tx49        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (40s ago)   3m41s
wordpress-mysql-8bcf9bcd6-jf4ts   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5 (34s ago)   3m41s
```

```
kubectl logs wordpress-758cfb447d-2tx49  
chown: changing ownership of '.': Permission denied
```

```
 kubectl logs wordpress-mysql-8bcf9bcd6-jf4ts
2023-06-15 10:54:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.33-1.el8 started.
find: '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
find: '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql': Permission denied
```

I am running as root user

```
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 0
```

Am I missing something here
[1]: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kubernetes-wordpress

Comment: `hostPath` volumes in general can be unreliable, and I'd avoid them except in some specific cases of DaemonSets.  (They store content on the host system on whichever node the pod happens to run on; if a node is destroyed you'll lose data, and if you have multiple replicas they could have the same or different data.)  If you're trying to inject your code this way, can you build it into a custom Docker image instead?